# Can't Debugg using VS Code because it doesnt Find a local file

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Currently when I debbuging moves to *my_proyect* and run

```
/home/my_user/my_company/my_proyect/my_folder/my_code.py
```

However, I getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/my_data.csv'
```

I trying to change the cwd variable in *launch.json* inside *.vscode* as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "ENVIROMENT_EXECUTION": "local",
                "LOGGING_LEVEL": "info",
                "ENVIROMENT_STAGE": "develop",
                "ENVIROMENT_DEBUG": "yes"
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my_folder"
        }
    ]
}
```

The structure of the folders is:

```
my_proyect/my_folder/data/my_data.csv
my_proyect/my_folder/my_code.py
```

And inside the code I have the following lines:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv("data/my_data.csv")
```

I note that works perfect if I add `my_folder` to the path as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv("my_folder/data/my_data.csv")
```

But I can't do that because when I deploy my code in AWS Lambda it works perfect. So, Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code takes the **open folder** as the workspace. I have tested according to your directory structure, and there is no problem.

[image]

I open the `my_project` folder with VS Code and VS Code uses it as a workspace.

[image]

Below is my `launch.json`

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my_folder",
        }
    ]
}
```

**So, please modify your `cwd` configuration according to your workspace.**

---

---

**UPDATE:**

Open the folder using **File --> Open Folder...**

[image]

Here is your directory:

```
/home/my_user/my_company/my_proyect/my_folder/my_code.py
```

If you have `my_company` turned on then `"cwd"` is

```json
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my_proyect/my_folder/"
```

If you have `my_user` turned on then `"cwd"` is

```json
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my_user/my_proyect/my_folder/"
```

*`${workspaceFolder}` is just a variable that represents the path to the folder you are currently opening as a workspace.*

Of course you can also use absolute path directly as `"cwd"`:

```json
"cwd": "/home/my_user/my_company/my_proyect/my_folder/my_code.py"
```